# proof of $\arctan(x)=\frac{i}{2}(\ln(x+i)-\ln(x-i)-i\pi)$ without solving $\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, logarithms

So I know $\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=\arctan(x)+c$

Now when i tried to integral $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ in a different way i got this:

$$\frac{1}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{(x-i)(x+i)}=\frac{A}{x-i}+\frac{B}{x+i}\\\implies1=Ax+Ai+Bx-Bi=x(A+B)+i(A-B)\\\implies
\begin{cases}
A+B=0
\\[2ex]
A-B=\frac{1}{i}=-i
\end{cases}\\\implies2A=-i\implies A=\frac{-i}{2}\implies B=\frac{i}{2}$$

So in the end i get:$$\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx=\int\frac{i}{2(x+i)}-\frac{i}{2(x-i)}dx=\frac{i}{2}\int\frac{1}{(x+i)}-\frac{1}{(x-i)}dx$$

After integrating this i get $\frac{i}{2}(\ln(x+i)-\ln(x-i)+C)$ after comparing this to $\arctan(x)$ at $x=0$ i find $C=-i\pi$

$\therefore~\arctan(x)=\frac{i}{2}(\ln(x+i)-\ln(x-i)-i\pi)$

now my question is how can i prove that without using the integral

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823688/arctan-x-frac12i-ln1-ix-ln1ix?rq=1

Comment: @MyGlasses thx for pointing who 2 out, i get how they done it in those 2, the only problem is the $C=-i\pi$ i got, why it doesn't appear at the first one you sent?

Comment: I'm sorry. I was confused those and worked on second. I think the title of that post is wrong and your proof shows it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of $\ln$ for complex numbers:
$$\ln(x+i)=\ln|x+i|+i\operatorname{Arg}(x+i)$$
where $\operatorname{Arg}$ is the principal value of the $\arg$

It is clear that:
$$\operatorname{Arg}(x+i)=\begin{cases}\arctan\frac{1}{x}&\text{ if }x\ge0\\\pi+\arctan\frac{1}{x}&\text{ if }x<0\end{cases}$$

Analogously:

$$\ln(x-i)=\ln|x-i|+i\operatorname{Arg}(x-i)$$
In this case it is:

$$\operatorname{Arg}(x-i)=\begin{cases}-\arctan\frac{1}{x}&\text{ if }x\ge0\\-\pi-\arctan\frac{1}{x}&\text{ if }x<0\end{cases}$$

Moreover observe that:
$|x+i|=|x-i|$

Putting everything together you get:

$\frac{i}{2}(\ln(x+i)-\ln(x-i)-i\pi)=\begin{cases}\stackrel{x\ge0}=\frac{i}{2}(2i\arctan\frac{1}{x}-i\pi)&=-\arctan\frac{1}{x}+\frac{\pi}{2}=\\\stackrel{x<0}=\frac{i}{2}(2i\pi+2i\arctan\frac{1}{x}-i\pi)&=-\arctan\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\pi}{2}=\end{cases}=\arctan x$

Comment: You made a mistake at the last part, you wrote $\ln(x+i)-\ln(x+i)$ and not $\ln(x+i)-\ln(x-i)$

Comment: @Holo Thanks. I'm going to edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using Euler? 
$$ z= \tan w = \frac{\sin w}{\cos w} = \frac{1}{i}\frac{e^{iw}-e^{-iw}}{e^{iw}+e^{iw}} = \frac{1}{i} \frac{e^{2iw}-1}{e^{2iw}+1}$$
so for any $k\in {\Bbb Z}$ $$e^{2iw} = e^{2i(w -k)} = \frac{1+iz}{1-iz}$$
whence 
$$ w = \frac{1}{2i} \log \left( \frac{1+iz}{1-iz} \right) +  k \pi$$
where the choice of $k\in {\Bbb Z}$ depends upon the cut you want.
$k=0$ corresponds to standard choices of $\log(1)=0$ and $\arctan 0=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You found
$$\arctan x=\dfrac{i}{2}\Big(\ln(x+i)-\ln(x-i)-i\pi\Big)=\dfrac{i}{2}\ln\dfrac{x+i}{x-i}+\dfrac{\pi}{2}=-\dfrac{i}{2}\ln\dfrac{x-i}{x+i}+\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$
let $x=\dfrac1z$ so
$$\arctan\dfrac1z=-\dfrac{i}{2}\ln\dfrac{1-iz}{1+iz}+\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$
and then
$$\dfrac{i}{2}\ln\dfrac{1-iz}{1+iz}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-\arctan\dfrac1z=\arctan z$$
as you want!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to look at this: consider that $z=|z|e^{i\theta}$ and that $z^*=|z^*|e^{-i\theta}$. Then

$$
\frac{|z|}{|z^*|}=e^{2i\theta}\\
\theta=\frac{1}{2i}(\ln |z|-\ln |z^*|)
$$

Now, let $z=x+i$, then

$$
\theta=\cot^{-1}x=\frac{1}{2i}(\ln |x+i|-\ln |x-i|)
$$

Now,

$$
\cot^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}x=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$

so that

$$
\begin{align}
\tan^{-1}x
&=-\frac{1}{2i}(\ln |x+i|-\ln |x-i|)+\frac{\pi}{2}\\
&=\frac{i}{2}(\ln |x+i|-\ln |x-i|-i\pi)
\end{align}
$$