Is my formula for the integral: $\int \frac{1}{x^{k}+1}dx$ correct?
First, I calculated the integral with the result:
$$\int \frac{1}{x^{7}+1}dx = \frac{1}{7}e^{\frac{-6i\pi}{7}}\ln\lvert{x-e^{\frac{i\pi}{7}}}\rvert+ \frac{1}{7}e^{\frac{-4i\pi}{7}}\ln\lvert{x-e^{\frac{3i\pi}{7}}}\rvert+ \frac{1}{7}e^{\frac{-2i\pi}{7}}\ln\lvert{x-e^{\frac{5i\pi}{7}}}\rvert+  \frac{1}{7}\ln\lvert{x+1}\rvert+ \frac{1}{7}e^{\frac{2i\pi}{7}}\ln\lvert{x-e^{\frac{9i\pi}{7}}}\rvert+ \frac{1}{7}e^{\frac{4i\pi}{7}}\ln\lvert{x-e^{\frac{11i\pi}{7}}}\rvert+ \frac{1}{7}e^{\frac{6i\pi}{7}}\ln\lvert{x-e^{\frac{13i\pi}{7}}}\rvert+c$$
Then, I generalised two things from it in the following:
$$x^{k}+1= \prod_{n=1}^{k}(x-{e^{\frac{(2n-1)i\pi}{k}}})$$
$$\int\frac{1}{x^{k}+1}dx = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{n=1}^{k} {e^{\frac{-(2n-1)(k-1)i\pi}{k}}}\ln\lvert{x-e^{\frac{(2n-1)i\pi}{k}}}\rvert$$
For $k=5$, I got:
$$\int \frac{1}{x^{5}+1}dx = \frac{1}{5}e^{\frac{-4i\pi}{5}}\ln\lvert{x-e^{\frac{i\pi}{5}}}\rvert+ \frac{1}{5}e^{\frac{-2i\pi}{5}}\ln\lvert{x-e^{\frac{3i\pi}{5}}}\rvert+\frac{1}{5}\ln\lvert{x+1}\rvert+\frac{1}{5}e^{\frac{2i\pi}{5}}\ln\lvert{x-e^{\frac{-3i\pi}{5}}}\rvert+ \frac{1}{5}e^{\frac{4i\pi}{5}}\ln\lvert{x-e^{\frac{-i\pi}{5}}}\rvert+c$$
Now my question: Is this all true? If so, how can I prove it, or is this enough? I'm really stuck. Thank you very much!

You can factor $x^k+1$ over the complex numbers. Every root is a power of $e^{\pi i/k}$. Then you can decompose $\frac{1}{x^k+1}$ into a sum of partial fractions and integrate term-by-term. But then you have a complex-linear combination of complex logarithms, and you need to make sure the answer is real-valued.

@MatthewLeingang So now the proof would be that instead of using the formula, I do it again by hand and then see if it comes out the same? But how do I really know that it is the solution of the integral? Because when I equate it to Wolframalpha, it doesn't come out right or wrong.

You can check your results against this WolframAlpha evaluation.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1999869/96384 , and many questions are linked from there. Compare also the ideas in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2807302/96384

@TorstenSchoeneberg The general formula: Why doesn't $\arctan(\frac{b}{a})$ apply here and if I multiply both summands of the antiderivative by x_k, do all real parts and all imaginary parts drop out? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1999869/96384

I don't understand your question. The fundamental misunderstanding here still seems to be that you wrongly believe the integral of $\frac{1}{z-c}$ is $\ln |z-c|$ for complex variables / numbers $c$, which it is not. Also, you should not multiply anything by $x_k$, but group together conjugates $x-c$ and $x-\bar c$, then use that $\arctan(x) = \frac{i}{2} (\log(i+x) -\log(i-x))$.

That doesn't look correct, already for $k=2$ because $\frac{1}{2}(-i\ln(|t-i|)+i\ln(|t+i|))=0$ for any $t\in\mathbb{R}$.
I'll treat the case $k=7$ but the following method works in general.
For $k\in[\![0;6]\!]$, write $\theta_k := \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{7}$ and $w_k:=\exp(i\theta_k)$. Notice that $\overline{w_k}=w_{6-k}$
$$X^7+1=\prod_{j=0}^6\left(X-w_j\right)$$
Therefore $$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{X^7+1}&=\frac{1}{7}\sum_{j=0}^6\frac{w_j^6}{X-w_j}\\
& =\frac{1}{7}\sum_{j=0}^2\frac{\overline{w_j}}{X-w_j}+\frac{\overline{w_{6-j}}}{X-w_{6-j}}+\frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{X+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{7}\sum_{k=0}^2\frac{2\cos(\theta_k)X-2}{X^2-2\cos(\theta_k)+1}+\frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{X+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{7}\sum_{k=0}^2\cos(\theta_k)\frac{2X-2\cos(\theta_k)}{X^2-2\cos(\theta_k)X+1}+\frac{-2\sin^2(\theta_k)}{(X-\cos(\theta_k)^2+\sin(\theta_k)^2}+\frac{1}{7}\frac{1}{X+1}
\end{align}$$
And $$\int\frac{dx}{x^7+1} = \frac{1}{7}\sum_{k=0}^2\cos(\theta_k)\ln(x^2-2\cos(\theta_k)x+1)-2\sin(\theta_k)\arctan\left(\frac{x-\cos(\theta_k)}{\sin(\theta_k)}\right)+\frac{1}{7}\ln(|1+x|)$$
It's not difficult to show that $$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{7}e^{\frac{-(2n-1)6i\pi}{7}}\ln\lvert{x-e^{\frac{(2n-1)i\pi}{7}}}\rvert&=\sum_{n=1}^3e^{\frac{-(2n-1)6i\pi}{7}}\ln\lvert{x-e^{\frac{(2n-1)i\pi}{7}}}\rvert+e^{\frac{(2n-1)6i\pi}{7}}\ln\lvert{x-e^{\frac{-(2n-1)i\pi}{7}}}\rvert+\ln|x+1| \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^3 2\cos\left(\frac{(2n-1)i\pi}{7}\right)\ln(|x-e^{\frac{(2n-1)i\pi}{7}}|)+\ln|x+1|\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^3 2\cos\left(\frac{(2n-1)i\pi}{7}\right)\ln\left(\sqrt{\left|x^2-2\cos\left(\frac{(2n-1)i\pi}{7}\right)+1\right|}\right)+\ln|x+1|\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^3 \cos\left(\frac{(2n-1)i\pi}{7}\right)\ln\left(\left|x^2-2\cos\left(\frac{(2n-1)i\pi}{7}\right)+1\right|\right)+\ln|x+1|\\
\end{align}$$
So you're missing the $\arctan$ part of the antiderivative.

I understand the answer, but somehow I don't either. Where exactly was the fault that it didn't work for me? I would just like to use my way.

@Mordor_07 It's not true that $\ln|x+z|$ is an antiderivative of $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x+z}$ (for $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$). The former is real valued and there's no reason why the later should be as well.

Hm, okay, that's how I've always done it in the real number range. How should I do it now in the complex number range?

@Mordor_07 Like i did ? Find the real part and the imaginary part and integrate them separately. For example, for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $\frac{1}{x+i}=\frac{x-i}{x^2+1} $ so $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+1) -i\arctan(x)$ is an antiderivative.

I now have the first integral: $\frac{1}{7}\cdot{e^{\frac{-6i\pi}{7}}}\cdot\int(\frac{x}{x^{2}-2\cos(\frac{\pi}{7})x+1}-\frac{{e^{\frac{-i\pi}{7}}}}{x^{2}-2\cos(\frac{\pi}{7})x+1})dx$ But how do I solve this, please? Is it even possible by hand? Or just use Wolframalpha?

Ignoring branch issues for now, an antiderivative of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z+c}$ is the complex logarithm $\mathrm{Log}(z+c)$, which basically by definition is $=\ln |z+c| + i\cdot \mathrm{Arg}(z+c)$. The argument function $\mathrm{Arg}$ boils down to an arctan; if the variable is real, $z=x$, you get $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dx}{x+c} = \ln \left(\sqrt{(x+Re(c))^2 + Im(c)^2} \right) + i\cdot \arctan \left(\dfrac{Im(c)}{x+Re(c)}\right)$. Note how @Ayoub's $\int \dfrac{dx}{x+c} = \frac12 \ln(x^2+1) -i\arctan(x)$ is the special case $c=i$ of this, using $\arctan(1/x) = const - \arctan(x)$.

@Mordor_07 Everything can be computed by hand, that's exactly what i did in my answer. In your case, $\frac{e^{i\pi/7}}{x^2-2\cos(\frac{1}{7})x+1}$ is not the imaginary part of the first integral because $e^{i\pi/7}$ is not imaginary ! Find the real part and the imaginary part  first. The real part looks like the derivative of a $\ln(u)$, the imaginary part looks like the derivative of some $\arctan(v)$.

@Ayoub  I have now: $\frac{1}{x^{n}+1}$ integrated and after a partial fraction decomposition the integral came out, using the method from yesterday: $\frac{-1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\int\frac{x_kx}{x^2-2x_k_rx+1} -\frac{x_k_r\ast+i x_k_i\ast}{x^2-2x_k_rx+1}dx)$ How do I solve this now? $x_k=e^\frac{(2k-1)\cdot i\pi}{n}; x_k_r=\cos{\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{n}; x_k_i=\sin {\frac{(2k-1)\pi}{n}}}$

@TorstenSchoeneberg I've now posted the last integral here in the comments, then I'm done with it. What's the best way to solve this?
